# My Final thoughts

Tags: cipher

Probably a last try, good luck guys.
It's a message that I wrote in my native language, so you just need to translate if you get the logic. All of the special characters don't need to be decoded, they make part of the message

> 252214  188812. 188812 22 614 26232268 26 2412146131823262322 2312 87262416 1161115181320.  1813212215181142213722 132612 8126 61426 142213722 2591815192613722 24121412 51224228, 22 11269262522138 1126926 26 1122881226 10622 24121382220186 23222418219269 188812. 726155221 226 51215722 1126926 23181229 10622 8626 922811128726 21 1218 26 24129922726.
> 26722 211218 1522202615 241213192224229 26 2412146131823262322 22 762312 1426188. 261520614 231826, 822 226 1422 712913269 61426 1122881226 10622 2412138222022 92281215229 2288228 71811128 2322 1062225926-2426252227268, 226 51215712 241214 24229722126. 22 7192692215, 132612 51261422 11269242218912, 122591820262312 11129 762312.

Hint:

> 27=ç
>  i wanted to give you more, but it will make this a lot easier

Comment: Well, you will spend a bit of time to decode, but they logic is simple

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: Did i achieved the website requirements now @ChrisCudmore ? because with that, i already cut 50% of the difficulty

Comment: With the hint and your profile description, i think we have enough information to begin and to guess in which language the text (to decode) was written.

Comment: touché, i did forgot about my profile

Comment: Does this have to do with the [binary](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/58563/riki481)? ;)

Comment: @user477343 When i saw the hint, i checked the profile of the op to know the language. rot13 : Lbh whfg unir gb pbaireg gur ovanel qrfpevcgvba gb xabj gur ynathntr bs gur chmmyr.

Comment: @Narlore Well, too easy, then. I know exactly what it is. Narlore, I swear, if I answer this correctly, I will literally upvote your answers :D

Comment: @user477343 Thx ^^ but i have nothing for now, i tried differents things but nothing conclusive.

Comment: @Narlore I posted a partial answer. If you don't know where to go from your rot13 message, you can check my answer if you like :)

Comment: @user477343 I just read it and i am exactly at the same point since the beginning ^^. Even with the hint, i'm blocked.

Comment: @Narlore Hmm... I guess that makes two of us. I noticed there are common strings like `10622`, `188812` and the big one `2412146131823` consisting of at least two other regular shorter strings. I don't know if this helps though :\

Comment: here goes another hint: backwards

Comment: @Narlore the logic is correct, the puzzle its basically turning the letters into alphabet numbers. Difference is, that I've changed the order of the numbers backwards. So instead of a = 1, is z = 1.

Comment: Isn't this puzzle just trial and error in inserting spaces between the letters until it looks like language, now that you've given away the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plaintext:

> BEM ISSO. ISSO E UM ADEUS A COMUNIDADE DO STACK PUZZLING. INFELIZMENTE NAO SOU UMA MENTE BRILHANTE COMO VOCES, E PARABENS PARA A PESSOA QUE CONSEGIU DECIFRAR ISSO. TALVEZ EU VOLTE PARA DIZER QUE SUA RESPOSTA FOI A CORRETA. ATE FOI LEGAL CONHECER A COMUNIDADE E TUDO MAIS. ALGUM DIA, SE EU ME TORNAR UMA PESSOA QUE CONSEGE RESOLER ESSES TIPOS DE QUEBRA - CABEÇAS, EU VOLTO COM CERTEZA. E THAREL, NAO VOU ME PARCEIRO, OBRIGADO POR TUDO.

Translation (from Google Translate):

> WELL THAT. THIS IS A GOODBYE TO THE STACK PUZZLING COMMUNITY. UNFORTUNATELY, I'M NOT A BRILLIANT MIND LIKE YOU, AND CONGRATULATIONS TO THE PERSON WHO DECIDED THIS. MAYBE I WILL COME BACK TO SAY YOUR ANSWER WAS THE CORRECT ONE. IT WAS NICE TO GET TO KNOW THE COMMUNITY AND EVERYTHING ELSE. SOMEDAY, IF I BECOME A PERSON WHO CAN SOLVE THESE TYPES OF PUZZLES, I WILL COME BACK FOR SURE. AND THAREL, I WILL NOT PARTNER, THANK YOU FOR EVERYTHING.

Solve path:

> After the setter gave away the substitution key in a comment, I decided to see if I could complete the solution using a computer program. I downloaded a Portuguese wordlist file and wrote some code to encrypt each word in the list individually. Then, I had the program take the ciphertext one word at a time and decrypt it by finding the word from the wordlist which has a matching encryption. This gave me about 90% of the solution:

> BEM ISSO. ISSO E UM ADEUS A COMUNIDADE DO 87262416 1161115181320. INFELIZMENTE NAO SOU UMA MENTE BRILHANTE COMO VOCES, E PARABENS PARA A PESSOA QUE 24121382220186 DECIFRAR ISSO. TALVEZ EU VOLTE PARA DIZER QUE SUA RESPOSTA 21 1218 A CORRETA. ATE FOI LEGAL CONHECER A COMUNIDADE E TUDO MAIS. ALGUM DIA, SE EU ME TORNAR UMA PESSOA QUE 2412138222022 92281215229 ESSES TIPOS DE QUEBRA - 2426252227268, EU VOLTO COM CERTEZA. E 7192692215, NAO 51261422 PARCEIRO, OBRIGADO POR TUDO.

> The remaining words were found through brief trial and error, since the letters `YZ` (corresponding to the digits `1` and `2`) are rare in Portuguese, so those digits are almost always in the tens place. I'm not sure about **7192692215 = THAREL**, but I suspect it is a name or proper noun.

Answer (score 5):

## Partial Answer

This is how you do it (thanks heaps to @[Narlore](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/47228/narlore)! Go upvote some of his/her content!)

First,

> Head to the profile to see the following binary: 
>  
>  [image: Binary]

Once I got that, I simply

> [decoded it](https://cryptii.com/pipes/binary-decoder)

and this gave me

> Sou um Estudante de TI iniciante. Procuro encontrar uma linguagem de programação que combine comigo.

After applying

> all the ROT functions in [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/), it became clear that no ROT was involved, and that this was a language.

So, inserting this in

> Google translate, in order to detect this language,

I got this:

> I'm a beginner IT student. I try to find a programming language that suits me.

was written in

> **Portugese**. (Note how the character ç is in this Portugese message, as also in the puzzle {due to the hint}) so it is likely that this is the language we are trying to get at.

With that being said, I also noticed

> there are common strings like `10622`, `188812` and the big one `2412146131823` consisting of at least two other regular shorter strings. But I am stuck on this part. They must represent words, or something. I know that there are 23 letters in the Portugese alphabet, so why would the hint be as  it is to begin with? Hmm... :\

Comment: 23 ? It's a latin alphabet so it's at least 26, i don't know if the specials characters like 'rr' or 'ç' count as letters or not.

Comment: @Narlore I don't think W, K and Y are included in the alphabet, but a quick google search reveals it has 23 letters... though there are a few sites that include the aforementioned three letters, thus making 26 in total. I am not too sure, to be honest.

Comment: On the wiki page of the alphabet we can see the 26 letters but you are right, the K, W, Y have a unusual use.

Comment: You guys need to see the alphabetic conversion to numbers backwards

Answer (score 0):

## PARTIAL ANSWER

I continue the answer of @[user477343](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42452/user477343) :


In the code we can observe

> the numbers 21, 22 and 26 are sometimes alone.

So I look at

> A "typical" portugese text and we can see the letters(characters) 'a', 'o' and 'e' alone.

So, I guess

> the numbers 21, 22 and 26 are 'a', 'o' or 'e'. We have to find which one now.